# XMLReader - Blank Page With No Errors

Tags: php, xml, magento, xmlreader, magmi

I'm trying to get the data from an XML file into an array so that I can import it via 'Magmi'. Using the following code, I'm working with a 3.6GB XML file.

```
<?php

$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open('wpcatsub.xml');

$doc = new DOMDocument;

// move to the first <App /> node
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'App');

// now that we're at the right depth, hop to the next <App/> until the end of the tree
while ($z->name === 'App')
{
    // either one should work
    //$node = new SimpleXMLElement($z->readOuterXML());
    $node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));

    // now you can use $node without going insane about parsing
    var_dump($node->element_1);

    // go to next <product />
    $z->next('App');
}

?>
```

When I load the PHP file, no errors appear -- the page is just blank. My XML data structure is below...

```
<App action="A" id="1">
    <BaseVehicle id= "17491"/>
    <Note><![CDATA[License Plate Lamp]]></Note>
    <Qty>.000</Qty>
    <PartType id= "10043"/>
    <Part>W0133-1620896</Part>
    <Product>
        <PartNumber>W0133-1620896</PartNumber>
        <BrandID>OES</BrandID>
        <BrandDescription><![CDATA[Genuine]]></BrandDescription>
        <WorldpacCategoryID>P9032</WorldpacCategoryID>
        <Price>29.85</Price>
        <ListPrice>33.17</ListPrice>
        <Available>Y</Available>
        <OEFlag>OEM</OEFlag>
        <Weight>.10</Weight>
        <Height>.7</Height>
        <Width>4.4</Width>
        <Length>4.4</Length>
        <SellingIncrement>1</SellingIncrement>
        <Popularity>D</Popularity>
        <ImageURL><![CDATA[http://img.eautopartscatalog.com/live/W01331620896OES.JPG]]></ImageURL>
        <ThumbURL><![CDATA[http://img.eautopartscatalog.com/live/thumb/W01331620896OES.JPG]]></ThumbURL>
    </Product>
    <ImageURL><![CDATA[http://img.eautopartscatalog.com/live/W01331620896OES.JPG]]></ImageURL>
    <ThumbURL><![CDATA[http://img.eautopartscatalog.com/live/thumb/W01331620896OES.JPG]]></ThumbURL>
</App>
```

Is it stalling because of the size of the file? If so, isn't XMLReader supposed to work for large XML files? If nothing else, what other options would I have?

I suppose I could load the XML data into a database if needed and then use SELECT queries to build the array for the MAGMI import. Though I'm not sure how to import an XML file into a SQL database. If need be, I'll be happy to get guidance with that.

Comment: If you have several `App` objects, you need to wrap them into a parent element. Then your XMLReader object will point at the parent element right after `open()`.

Comment: You're using XMLReader, DOMDocument and SimpleXMLElement, are you sure you need to use all 3 libraries for this? What do `print_r($z)` and `print_r($node)` show?

Comment: I'm using some example code which seems to work on smaller files but it won't work for this 3GB file. Is it possible it's still running out of memory even though it's supposed to go node to node?

Comment: You will need to enable error *logging* for this, also set the level to the highest level (everything incl. notices and warnings). Also you should report your libxml version: http://php.net/libxml.constants

Comment: Also you need to troubleshoot your code. At which line does it halt when the screen it blank *exactly*? Proof it by adding debug code.

Comment: I have the same problem (i.e. silent failure) when my XML lacks a DTD.  Seems like a bug.  It should at least report the failure.